# Index was outside the bounds of the array error in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I know this question has been answered many a times on this site but its bit different. Please see my issue

I want to **delete** row from the `gridview` by the below code:-

```
protected void GrdQualification_DeleteCommand(object sender, Obout.Grid.GridRecordEventArgs e)
{  
    if (Session["DtFilldata"] != null)
    {
        DtFilldata = (DataTable)Session["DtFilldata"];
    }
    else
    {
        BindDatatable();
    }

    DataRow[] advRow = DtFilldata.Select("Q_SRNO=" + Convert.ToString(e.Record["Q_SRNO"]));
    DtFilldata.Rows.Remove(advRow[0]);
    AddToViewState();
}
```

But I am getting error as

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

I checked links from the site but it didn't helped me.

Please suggest what Is wrong here

Comment: does the method DtFilldata.Select .... return data?

Comment: @أحمدصوالحة: Yes, it returns the row which I want to delete.

Comment: Check advRow Length.... if(advRow.Length>0){DtFilldata.Rows.Remove(advRow[0]);}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, while debugging I saw that `AddToViewState()` function was giving me the issue.

As it was making the function call again so it was going `Out of Index`. So I removed that and it worked as required.